# Fast / Convenient way to publish on Microsoft Azure Cloud Service Web Role

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I am new to Azure Cloud Service. I have created a Web Role in it.
Each time I want to do some updated in my Web Role application I have to create Package and upload it to Azure Cloud Service.
I have to do it for even a small design change (HTML Change).

Is there any better and fast way to upload cloud service/Web Role?

Thanks

Comment: Config for cloud services can be updated quickly. If files inside the package change, you have to go through the full update. It's a feature of cloud services :)

Comment: See if Azure App Service is a viable option for you instead of Cloud Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time to upload a package really depends on the internet speed at your disposal. With good speed, it usually takes a few seconds to upload MBs of a package. It is the deployment which takes time.

Azure Cloud Service, either Web Role or Worker Role, is a full Virtual Machine which gets instantiated when you deploy/re-deploy the package. The VM essentially takes the amount of time as a normal PC. There no workaround to lessen the time to launch of the VM.